# Creating new params in the Code is not working?

Tags: android, android-layout

This chunk of code doesnt seem to be doing its job.

```
line=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params==(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)line.getLayoutParams();
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.minSpinner);
line.setLayoutParams(params);
```

**Note all of these have been instantiated just not doing there job when put into emulator.  The line is supposed to move BELOW the Spinner.
Thanks in advance

Comment: the order is important: have you added the spinner before you add the imageview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried quickly implementing the layout in XML to make sure that BELOW is actually functioning as you're expecting? Relative layouts can be tricky to figure out without some trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `==` to `=`?

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params==(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)line.getLayoutParams();
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking.

Comment: that was a typo on my part I didnt actually have that My bad

Comment: Maybe you should show your XML or associated code, like where the parent RelativeLayout and Spinner are declared and laid out. Also, you should probably copy/paste from now on to avoid typos. They slow down debugging like nothing else.

Comment: Or even describe what "doesn't seem to be doing its job" means.